# How to input a string into a ViewHolder

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I would like to put in a string from a different class into the following code:

```
 public class FirebaseCommentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private View mView;
        private Context mContext;
        private String mphotoUserID;
        private String mUrl;


        public FirebaseCommentViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            mContext = itemView.getContext();

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void bindComment(final Comment comment) {
            TextView usernameTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.comment_username);
            TextView comment_textview = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.comment_textview);
            ImageButton moreOptionsImageButton = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.comment_more_options);


            mphotoUserID = comment.getCommenter();
            mUrl = PhotoUtilities.removeWebPFromUrl(comment.getPhoto_url());

            //usernameTextView.setText(comment.getCommenter());
            setCommentorsName(comment.getCommenter(), usernameTextView);
            comment_textview.setText(comment.getCommentString());
}

        public void setCommentorsName(String uid, final TextView usernameTextView) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FirebaseConstants.USERDATA).child(uid).child(FirebaseConstants.USERNAME)
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                                usernameTextView.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            usernameTextView.setText("BOB");
                        }
                    });
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ArrayList<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
    //      Reference correct section of database below
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseConstants.PHOTOS)
                    .child(mUrl).child(FirebaseConstants.COMMENTS);
            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        comments.add(snapshot.getValue(Comment.class));
                    }

    //                int itemPosition = getLayoutPosition();

    //                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, RestaurantDetailActivity.class);
    //
    //                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });

        }
```

The following is the code that I use in order to start the class:

```
private void setUpFirebaseAdapter() {
    mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comment, FirebaseCommentViewHolder>
            (Comment.class, R.layout.comment_template, FirebaseCommentViewHolder.class,
                    mCommentReference) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(FirebaseCommentViewHolder viewHolder,
                                          Comment model, int position) {
            viewHolder.bindComment(model);
        }
    };
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Basically I need to pass in the user ID from the code into the FirebaseCommentViewHolder class and I am unsure how as I have never implemented code like this before. I tried to add it to the constructor, but this did not work/get recognized by Android Studio. Any other tips would be greatly appreciated!

NOTE: I did delete some non relevant code so if brackets don't match up or something that would be why.

Comment: What different class? Put it where?

Comment: Just put in the id at `usernameTextView.setText`, which you commented out

Comment: what is the value of usernameTextView.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
is it the JSON from the Firebase ?

Comment: The usernameTextView is for something else. It is for the user which made the specific comment. I am trying to push over the current user from firebase.

Comment: @cricket_007 I am trying to put the string into the first class that I posted. The second block of code is how I initialize the first block of code.

Comment: in the dataSnapshot | setCommentorsName you are getting the hole JSON from the firebase you need a helper Class to store the values and then set the text in the textView

Comment: @Ben_Gratvol I'll fix that, thanks. Any idea on how I can pass a string from the second block of code into the first block of code (they are in 2 separate classes)

Comment: Just add a parameter to `bindComment` method for whatever extra data you need

Comment: create a comments Object and in the dataSnapshot | setCommentorsName  create a List of comments (to store the JSON ) then just pass to the comments to the textview

Comment: @cricket_007 This will add the comment to every single view. Isn't there a way to just toss this into the class once?

Comment: I already have that. I want to get the current user. This way I can check to see if the current user is the person who left the comment so that the current user will have the option to delete or edit the comment. Other users will not have that option.

Comment: just a sec ill post sum code

Comment: I don't understand the question, then. You wanted a variable in the ViewHolder. Each ViewHolder is a single view. If you add a variable into the ViewHolder, then yes, it will be part of *every single view*

Comment: @cricket_007 I meant for the whole FirebaseCommentViewHolder class. From what I understand, there is the part of the class that binds every single comment to every single view, but there is also the part of the class where it won't do that. Or am I mistaken here? If there was a way to pass the string into the constructor that would be ideal, however, I don't know how to pass it from the second part of the code. BTW passing it in to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter is also an option... but I have no clue how :/

Comment: Nevermind, I see how that is an issue with viewholder as it does make a new viewholder for each view. So, I might as well put it into the bindComment(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically I need to pass in the user ID from the code into the FirebaseCommentViewHolder class

I would just add a parameter

```
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(FirebaseCommentViewHolder viewHolder,
             Comment model, int position) {
        // Grab your userId from somewhere
        viewHolder.bindComment(model, userId);
    }
```

You can't add to the constructor of the ViewHolder because FirebaseUI is abstracting that away from your code.

You could alternatively extend the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and add it into **that** constructor

```
private void setUpFirebaseAdapter(final String userId) {
    // For example
    mFirebaseAdapter = new UserIdFirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comment, FirebaseCommentViewHolder>
            (userId, Comment.class, R.layout.comment_template, FirebaseCommentViewHolder.class,
                    mCommentReference) {
```

Either way, you would get it into the ViewHolder via the `bindComment()` method.